# Add columns selectively in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have the following data

......................Judge 1 | Judge 2 | Judge 3 | Total score

Contestant 1.......5.............3..............2 .......

Contestant 2.......3.............3..............6........

And I want to design some interface (I guess this could involve VBA, unless we can do without?) where I can select which judge's scores to add up.

So theoretically, there's a checklist where I have

[] Judge 1

[] Judge 2

[] Judge 3

[] Select all

Or something, and then if I press select all, the total score would sum up all the judge's scores. But if I unselect select all and just select Judge 1 and 2, then the scores would total up accordingly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it without VBA:

[image]

.

- Make a Data Validation rule for the first row: "List", Source: "Selected, Not Selected"
- Total Score formula: **`=SUMIF(B$2:D$2,"=Selected",B5:D5)`**

Total Score will update every time you select or deselect one of the judges